# mybatis: how to iterate a hashmap in a bean in mapper?

Tags: java, mybatis

mapper interface:

```
List<Map<String, String>> selectXXXList(BeanA a);
```

BeanA:

```
private Map<String, String> map;
```

I need iterate this map in xxxMapper.xml. I tried in this way, but it can not work.

```
<select id = "selectXXXList" resultType="hashMap">
   SELECT * FROM tableA
   WHERE
      1=1 
      <foreach collection="a.map.keys" item="item" index="index" open="" seperator="" close="">
      AND ${item} = #{a.map[${item}]}
      </foreach>
<select>
```

It is able to iterator the key in this way. But the value of hashMap `#{a.map[${item}]}` does not work. Any idea? I can not change the interface BTW.

Comment: @VinayHegde it is a dynamic query , I want to use key as column value as condition in WHERE

Comment: @VinayHegde it is like select * from tableA where HASHMAP_KEY_A = HASH_VALUE_A and HASHMAP_KEY_B = HASHMAP_VALUE_B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<select id="selectXXXList" parameterType="beanA" resultType="hashmap">    
    select * from TABL where 
    <foreach  collection="map"  index="key" item="value"  open=""  separator=" and "  close="">
        ${key}=#{value}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

Comment: My parameterType has to be beanA, which is not a HASHMAP.

Comment: Thanks , I would try it. But I don’t think it work.

Comment: I think mybaits can not obtain the flied in a bean in this way. I am not sure,XD.

Comment: Ah, I know this way work. But I have to use a bean as parameter.

Comment: Replace `#{key}` with `${key}` and this should work. [Here](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-57832384) is a portable demo.

Comment: @VinayHegde yeah, it works. But I need to remove the parameterType condition. Thank you!